# Error with .addNumberOption (slash command)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make a commander (cmd slash) to activate maintenance on a remote server. Most of the order is done and functional. But when I want to put the number of minutes via a `.addNumberOption`, I get the error

> Option "minutes" is of type: 10; expected 3.

```js
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('maintenancemc-staff')
    .setDescription('Active ou désactive le mode maintenance du serveur Minecraft')
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('raison')
        .setDescription('Raison du changement de statut')
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName('minutes')
        .setDescription("Décompte d'activation du mode maintenance en minute")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
      await interaction.deferReply({ fetchReply: true, ephemeral: true });
      const { options } = interaction; 
      const raison = options.getString("raison");
      const timer = options.getString("minutes");
...
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `addNumberOption`, instead of `options.getString("minutes")`, you need to use [`options.getNumber("minutes")`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getNumber).

Comment: It was all stupid, thank you!